# Cant change neo4j password

Tags: curl, command-line, neo4j, ubuntu-16.04, change-password

I am trying to change my neo4j password through the following command line operation, following Brent Barbata's answer on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645951/how-to-configure-user-and-password-for-neo4j-cluster-without-rest-api)

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST -d '{"password":"new_password"}' -u neo4j:neo4j http://localhost:7474/user/neo4j/password
```

But I am getting the following error

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "code" : "Neo.ClientError.Security.Unauthorized",
    "message" : "Invalid username or password."
  } ]
```

I tried this alternate way following the ideas from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38540095/curl-node-how-to)

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json"\ -H "Authorization: Basic `echo -n 'USERNAME:OLDPASSWORD | base64`"\ -X POST -d '{"password":"NEWPASSWORD"}'\ -I http://localhost:7474/user/neo4j/password
```

And got the following error

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Authorization
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: POST
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "code" : "Neo.ClientError.Security.Unauthorized",
    "message" : "No authentication header supplied."
  } ]
```

Whats wrong in these methods and what is the way to change password?
I do not want to use `:server change-password` on browser. I am running neo4j 3.3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's to initially set the password (i.e. before the first start of the server):

```
bin/neo4j-admin set-initial-password MyNewPassWord
```

If it's to change your password, just connect to the cypher-shell with your login/password and then execute this query:

```
CALL dbms.security.changePassword('MyNewPassWord')
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried out your examples on my own instance of Neo4j and was met with the same errors. I found this slightly different command from [this](http://www.booneputney.com/development/update-neo4j-password-via-curl/) source and this works for me. No error messages are returned and it instantly changes your password.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Basic `echo -n 'USERNAME:OLDPASSWORD' | base64`" -X POST -d '{"password":"NEWPASSWORD"}' -I http://localhost:7474/user/neo4j/password
```

It looks almost exactly the same as the second curl command in your question - my guess is, with the line continuation characters and the general messiness of the entire command, it's possible that when you ran the command, one of the command options/flags did not have a space either before or after it which confused the interpreter. It probably goes without saying, but make sure you replace the USERNAME, OLDPASSWORD and NEWPASSWORD placeholders with the actual values before running the command.